# Did Top Gear participate in A Good Day To Die Hard?

Tags: top-gear, a-good-day-to-die-hard

There was an episode of Top Gear (UK) where they participated in the making of [The Sweeney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sweeney_%282012_film%29). They had to do a car chase scene and ruined the movie. But at the end of that episode, Jeremy Clarkson said that Top Gear guys are filming some scenes for the new die hard movie in Russia.

I watched the entire movie, and it doesn't seem to me that Top Gear participated in that movie, in fact there's no real car chase, in the movie, except that scene where Bruce Willis is chasing the bad guys in traffic jam, and it doesn't seem that Top Gear filmed that scene.

So did Top Gear had anything to do with A Good Day To Die Hard? Or were their scenes deleted or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Top gear helped with [promoting](http://www.topgear.com/uk/photos/a-good-day-to-die-hard-behind-the-scenes-mercedes-2013-02-05) the film. [This](http://www.topgear.com/uk/car-news/a-good-day-to-die-hard-car-chase-mercedes-g-wagen-2013-02-01) is also posted on the top gear website. Other than that I find no involvement between the production of Die Hard 5 and the staff of Top Gear.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say, but if you have a look at S19E04 of Top Gear, you'll see Bruce Willis testing the horn. And in the background you see something that looks like the set of Die Hard.

Answer (score 0):

Ben might also be moonlighting as the stunt driver for the scenes in Die Hard. The stunt driving rig used in the movie, is very much similar to that of Skyfall, where I know for fact, the old stig was the stunt driver. So this, with Bruce Willis testing the horn on Kia C'eed 2 in the Chernobyl studio setting I feel TopGear or some of TopGear's crew had some hand.

Answer (score -1):

I would go out on a limb and suggest that the endscene, the last 6-8 minutes, are shot at the Top Gear testtrack. Check it out.
All the best